# Is it possible to change the Windows Color Scheme with a macro?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macros, colors, color-theme

E.g., 32-bit Windows 7 here:

[image: Windows Color Scheme Dialog]

The alternative is tediously going through the Control Panel each time you want to switch.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you are referring to **High Contrast** color scheme.

You can toggle between high contrast and standard color scheme using
left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> (Print Screen).

This switches between last color scheme from each set (i.e. between your last standard color scheme and your last high contrast color scheme).

There are also other possibilities, but this one was the simplest. If you need to know more, then please describe your specific need (update your question).